# self incrementing array destruction? Node.js

Tags: json, node.js

example,

```
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
{

console.log(jsonfile[i].Username)

}
```

I tried this, and got the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Username' of undefined
```

my JSON is:

```
[
    {
        "Username": "ozziep",
        "ProjectID": "ExpressJS",
        "TimeStamp": "2016-12-30T19:54:52.418Z",
        "Comments": "hello world how are we today?"
    }
]
```

I am loading the JSON in using require.

Comment: That's going to fail on the second loop as jsonFile[1] does not exist

Comment: There's only one item in the array... so when you get to the second iteration, `jsonfile[1]` is empty.

Comment: Use `i < jsonfile.length`, instead. Voting to close, since this is a common rookie error.

Comment: @Tom Why are you using a fixed length instead of `jsonfile.length` in your loop?

Comment: it was a snippet, I have 6 of the same, but with different content.

Comment: I have changed to use for var in, so that bit works, but I need to get a self incrementing variable to make the array destruction count up also, can I put a for with in another for?

Answer (score 0):

As there is only one object in your `jsonfile`, `jsonFile[1]` will be undefined.

Instead of `i < 5` use `i < jsonfile.length` like below :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < jsonfile.length; i ++)
 {
  console.log(jsonfile[i].Username)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick but thank you all for your input.

```
for( var user in jsonfile) {
   console.log(jsonfile[user].Username);
   console.log("------------------------")
   console.log(jsonfile[user].Comments);
   console.log("------------------------")
   console.log(jsonfile[user].ProjectID);
   console.log("------------------------")
   console.log("")
```

}